# How can i create imessage extension by cmake

Tags: xcode, cmake

In cmake documents i can only find add_executable() command to create an app target.Is someone who know how to create an extension by cmake like imessage extension here? Please give me some suggestion.Thanks very much!

Comment: These "imessage extensions" you are talking about seem to be a libraries written in Objective C. I'd start searching how to use CMake to build ObjC projects, if you really need use CMake for this.

Comment: The "imessage extensions" is an xcode target template.The extension will be compiled into a ".appex" program.It can run alone and publish to the apple imessage store. Now i can't find a cmake command to create this extension style app.

Comment: If not use cmake,usually we can create it by xcode menu. file->new->target->imessage extension.